# C++ initializer list inside of a template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, initializer-list

I would like to get to know C++11 a little bit more, So I wrote the simplest possible initializer_list test I knew, but inside of a template, this is a "free" function, 
and I get this error whenever I compile it (clang++ for pretty formatting)

```
/home/alex/repo/mine/mlcppl/test/utiltest1.cc:16:3: error: no matching function for call to 'makevec'
mlcppl::makevec<string> ({"alex", "herrmann"});
```

Here is the code:

```
namespace mlcppl{
 template<typename Tp> vector<Tp> makevec (initializer_list<Tp> initlist)
 {
   vector<Tp> vt;
   for(Tp x : initlist)
     {
       vt.insert(vt.end(), x);
     }
  return vt;
  }
 }
```

and here is where it is called:

```
#include <util.hh>
int main()
{
  vector<string> vc;
  vc = makevec<string> ({"alex", "herrmann"});
  return 0;
}
```

I have no clue why this would happen, Any suggestions?

Comment: You are calling `makevec` with a namespace qualifer. Is the `makevec` implementation actually defined in the `mlcppl` namespace? Your example doesn't show it.

Comment: yes it is, hold on, let me put whole def in post

Comment: That code should work fine. What version of clang? Also the body of makevec could simply be replaced with `return initlist;`

Comment: The code is still missing some namespace qualifiers, using-declarations, and/or using-directives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works with g++ (Ideone):

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

template<typename Tp> std::vector<Tp> makevec (std::initializer_list<Tp> initlist) { return initlist; }

int main() { makevec<std::string> ({"alex", "herrmann"}); }
```

Which clang++?

Comment: @Mooing Duck: Don't be ridiculous. It contains code -- how is emsr supposed to put that into a comment?

Comment: 3.0, and it did compile just fine with gcc..... hrmmmm, should I try a newer version?

Comment: @alexhairyman Initializer lists weren't done until 3.1 http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html (N.B. Apple uses slightly different versions than the ones listed on this page.)

Comment: Thanks for the info!! Ubuntu repositories must have not been updated to latest version! thanks everybody!

Comment: Pangolin only has llvm 3.0.  Sigh.

Comment: @TonyK: Ideone links, like everyone else.